# How to output dates properly formatted in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on an android app at school. I am currently building a notepad. I would like to know if there are any ways to get the date and store it into the sqlite database as a date format and then, when I am retrieving it from the database and write it into my textview, I could display `hh::mm` if the note was written/modified today, or `dd/mm/yy` if it were (let's say) written yesterday. To be more clear:

1. I write a note
2. I get the date
3. I insert everything into my database table
4. Retrieve the data into a ListView
5. for each note, I want to display the date in the right format,( if the date was the same day, just display the hh:mm, yesterday if it was written yesterday, else display dd/mm/yy

Also, which way is better to store the date into database, as Date format? I searched online and it appears that there are several ways to do it, which one is the best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date can be converted to `long` value (number of milliseconds passed from Jan, 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC+0000).

It surely is the most convenient presentation of date:

1. `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns current date in this format;
2. This format is used to set an alarm using `AlarmManager`;
3. Easy to determine which date is earlier (just compare two long values - less is earlier);
4. Easy to store in the database or using `SharedPreferences`.

`Calendar` class which is standard for date operations in Java, also supports this format - it has `setTimeInMillis()` and `getTimeInMillis()` functions.

For more details, refer to the documentation on [`Calendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) class.

As for different date formats, check out the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.

Comment: Thank you for your response. One more thing, if I want to insert the date in my sqlite database, how could I do that? I need to do long date = System.currentTimeMillis() and insert it into my database as date?

Comment: @AndréHincu just store it as INTEGER value. No need to convert it to DATE.

Comment: and then when I retrieve my date from my database, how do I make it do display it as hh:mm(for today), yesterday (for yesterday) and dd//mm/yy for the rest?

Comment: `Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance(); calendar.setTimeInMillis(your_long_value_retrieved_from_database);` and then you can retrieve day, month, year, etc. separately, or `Date` object using `getTime()` function.